# NGINX-RTMP-Module : Can't record

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I would like to make a thumbnail of the current stream. According to [this](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/356) post it's possible by using a recorded block.

Unfortunatly I cannot make it work. Nothing happens. Checked error.log nothing in there too.
I also tryed to record just in flv but same issue as previously.

Below is my nginx.conf

Note : The rtmp stream is live (Don't know if that makes a difference)

Note 2 : I used sudo mkdir /usr/local/nginx/var/rec

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                    live on;
                    recorder preview {
                        record keyframes;
                        record_max_frames 4;
                        record_path /var/rec;
                        record_interval 30s;

                        exec_record_done ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:7000/live/$name -vcodec png -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 -ss 00:00:01 -y /var/rec/test.png;
                    }


            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the line `record all`